# supertest: test the redirection url

Tags: node.js, supertest

with supertest, I can test the redirection code 302

```
var request = require('supertest');
var app = require('../server').app;

describe('test route', function(){
  it('return 302', function(done){
    request(app)
      .get('/fail_id')
      .expect(302, done);
  });
  it('redirect to /');
});
```

how I can test the url objetive to redirect ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  it('redirect to /', function(done){
    request(app)
      .get('/fail_id')
      .expect('Location', /\//, done);
  });
```

Answer (score 12):

@JuanPablo's answer is on the right path (pun intended), but it will match any location with `/` anywhere.

You want to make sure that there is nothing following the `/` by using the line-end char `$`, and that the chars previous to the `/` are what you expect. A quick-and-dirty example follows:

```
it('redirect to /', function(done){
  request(app)
    .get('/fail_id')
    .expect('Location', /\.com\/$/, done);
});
```